# TYPO3 EXT:form TypoScript override for a field by its identifier in all forms

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-form

I have multiple forms and all have a privacy checkbox which is identified by `identifier: privacyCheckbox` and I want to dynamically render/override some configuration by typoscript.

This really works fine, if I exactly know the form's identifier and the field's position:

```
plugin.tx_form {
  settings {
    formDefinitionOverrides {

      # "defaultContact" is my form's name
      defaultContact {
        renderables {
          0 {
            renderables {
              # "7" is the order/position of the privacy field in the form definition
              7 {
                renderingOptions {
                  translation {
                    arguments {
                      label {
                        0 = TEXT
                        0.typolink {
                          parameter = {$global.pids.privacyPage}
                          returnLast = url
                          forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of "7" I even could use `aSpecificKey`, if my YAML form definition would look like ...

```
    renderables:
      myEmailKey:
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: email
        label: E-Mail
      aSpecificKey:
        type: Checkbox
        identifier: privacyCheckbox
```

But I want the editor allow to edit the form and rearange the fields, so it always will be saved as ...

```
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: email
        label: E-Mail
      -
        type: Checkbox
        identifier: privacyCheckbox
```

... which would cause an internal numeric array of all fields.

So, now my questions:

- Is there a way to apply my override settings for all forms and not to have to apply it to every form by its name?
- Is there another way to apply the overrides to a field without manually modifying the generated YAML or counting the field's position in the form? I mean, I have set `identifier: privacyCheckbox` in the definition - is it right, that I cannot use this identifier to access a field?

Comment: Could you solve this task? I would be interested.